# manipulate current time in unit testing?

Tags: java, time, junit

Is there any way to manipulate the current time in a jUnit 4.5 test? I have the following method which I'd like to have a unit test for

```
public String getLastWeek() {
  GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Stockholm"));
  c.setFirstDayOfWeek(GregorianCalendar.MONDAY);
  c.add(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
  return c.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + " " + c.get(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
}
```

One way to make it easier to test is to split it into two methods

```
public String getLastWeek() {
  GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Stockholm"));
  return getLastWeekFor(c);
}

public String getLastWeekFor(GregorianCalander c) {
  c.setFirstDayOfWeek(GregorianCalendar.MONDAY);
  c.add(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
  return c.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + " " + c.get(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
}
```

That lets me test the week subtraction logic, but leaves getLastWeek untested and I prefer to have just one method for this.

Comment: Acutally, it's just one method, only with two different parameter lists :)

Answer (score 6):

You have no real way of manipulating system time.

Actually, you refactored the method rather nicely in order to make it testable. I would keep it at that.

Answer (score 3):

I can see two paths here.

Either, create a `DateUtils` factory class, which encapsulates the construction of `Calendar` and `Date` instances. Then you can swap this for a controllable factory. I.e., you have a second implementation of `DateUtils` that also exposes a `setCurrentTime` method, and will then explicitly return `Calendar` instances set to that date.

Or, you can use JMockit to actually "redefine" your call of `new GregorianCalendar` so instead a mock instance is returned. I have not done this myself, but there is a description [here](http://fromthesource.liquidorange.net/?p=69).

Your option, breaking the method into two methods, is also a perfectly valid option. I think that it is what most people do - including myself: but the truth is that it does hurt your design, especially if the class is exposed to other code.

Comment: The first two suggestions, while are perfectly valid and even heavily used in other situations, feel a bit of an overkill to OP's needs.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to recreate what [JODA](http://joda.org/) Time does.  I'll cite it in case you aren't aware.  You can make the trade-off between reinventing the wheel and adding a dependency.

Comment: Actully I found JODA earlier today and realised that was what I actully wanted to be using. How would a testable JODA version look? Or should I simply assume that JODA is working correct as it should have it's own tests?

Comment: Check the JODA source out and see if it's unit tested.  I'm betting that it is.  Usually I assume a 3rd party library is tested until it gives me a reason to believe otherwise.  At worst, they have a bigger user base than you do.  Lots of people banging on code is a good way to find and fix lots of errors.